# Data is not fetched from database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, project

I am trying to get data from others table but when I join serviceplan table the result of query is empty but when I remove serviceplan table its fetched data perfectly.

Here is the code of my Model(without serviceplan table-working)

```
public function send_mail() {
    // $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $query=$this->db->select('*, employee.name_emp as emp_name, customer.name as cust_name, servicetype.name_set as s_name',
        'serviceplan.price as p_rice')->from('appointment')
        // ->where('id_app',$appointment_id)
        ->join('customer', 'customer.id= appointment.name_app')
        ->join('servicetype', 'servicetype.id_set= appointment.sertype')
        ->join('employee', 'employee.id_emp= appointment.emp')
        // ->join('serviceplan', 'serviceplan.id_sep= appointment.price_app')
        ->get();

    echo $this->db->last_query();
    exit();        
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: for join data type should be same. Because join compare values. string cannot be compared with integer

Comment: if there is no same data in serviceplan and appointment then its return empty try left join.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal joins or Inner Join only gets the rows common in both the tables. So, in your case, there are not matching conditions in your `serviceplan` table.

Verify it. Or look upon your requirements and try using `leftjoin` instead of `join`.

Also look: [Difference between joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this simple join table query using codeigniter as below:

```
$email='myEmail@test.com';
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->where('table1.email',$email);
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.email = table2.email');
$query = $this->db->get();
$assignedData=$query->result_array();
```